# How to use Onclick event in <Script> tag to show a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, dom-events

I am trying to code to hide and display a `<div>` after clicking on an ad from any site. This ad is the result of a script. So how can I use onclick event in `<script>` tag?

My code:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

<div class="bnrdiv" onClick="myFunction()">
       <script type="text/javascript">
var ad_idzone = "3265310",
     ad_width = "468",
     ad_height = "60";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ads.exdynsrv.com/ads.js"></script>
<noscript><iframe src="https://syndication.exdynsrv.com/ads-iframe-display.php?idzone=3265310&output=noscript&type=468x60" width="468" height="60" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"></iframe></noscript>
       </div>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? Is `bnrdiv` not the DIV with the ad in it?

Comment: The ads probably have their own click handlers to link you to the site they're advertising, and it may use `event.stopPropagation()` so the click event never bubbles out to your DIV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Jquery envent .toggle()

```
<!-- Call Jquery libs -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        // When thue user clicks an ad
        // the .bnrdiv contains the ad
        $('.bnrdiv').click(function () {
            $('#myDIV').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="bnrdiv">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ad_idzone = "3265310",
            ad_width = "468",
            ad_height = "60";
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ads.exdynsrv.com/ads.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <iframe src="https://syndication.exdynsrv.com/ads-iframe-display.php?idzone=3265310&output=noscript&type=468x60"
            width="468" height="60" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </noscript>
</div>

<div id="myDIV">
    This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please recheck this.. while  <style>
#myDIV {
  display:none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.bnrdiv {
width:100px;
}
</style>

Comment: Does your ad container (<div class="bnrdiv"></div>) has an element?

Comment: yes it has.. 
<div class="bnrdiv">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ad_idzone = "3265310",
            ad_width = "468",
            ad_height = "60";
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ads.exdynsrv.com/ads.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <iframe src="https://syndication.exdynsrv.com/ads-iframe-display.php?idzone=3265310&output=noscript&type=468x60"
            width="468" height="60" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </noscript>
</div>
<div id="myDIV">
    This is my DIV.
</div></body>

Comment: Try to add something like `console.log('clicked');` inside the click event to test if we clicked the right ad and look at your console ...

Comment: Can you please create your own code complete with css, jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this.

The advert and browsers' defences against [clickjacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) are going to consume the click before your code has any chance to detect it.

---

*Warning*: It sounds like you are trying to incentivise people clicking on adverts (click the advert to see the content) which violates the terms and conditions of most advertising services.